# Remove any line in rtb1 from rtb2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I have a2 richtext box first one called a1 second one b2 . Both of them have texts

What im trying to do is : delete any line that a2 has from b2
So if a2 contain lines 
First line = 1256
Second one = 5678 
....etc
I want to remove any line in b2 that contain this lines in a2 1256 and 5678 ..etc

I tried to use filter but that took long time because there are alot of lines and didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve your problem so i reached to this(it's not completely what you want but it may help you) :

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim CheckChar, CheckedChar As String
    Dim CheckedNum As Integer = 1

    Private Sub CheckBUT_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBUT.Click
        If Not a1.Text = "" Then
            If a1.Text.Length > 2 Then
ReRead:         If CheckedNum = 1 Then
                    CheckChar = a1.Text.Remove(1)
                Else
                    CheckChar = a1.Text.Substring(CheckedNum - 1)
                    If Not CheckedNum = a1.Text.Length Then
                        CheckChar = CheckChar.Remove(1)
                    End If
                End If
                If CheckChar.Contains("" & vbLf & "") Then
                    CheckedChar = a1.Text.Remove(CheckedNum - 1)
                    CheckChar = b2.Find(CheckedChar)
                    If Not CheckChar = -1 Then
                        b2.Text = b2.Text.Replace(CheckedChar & ("" & vbLf & ""), "")
                    End If
                Else
                    a1.Text.Substring(CheckedNum - 1)
                End If
                If CheckedNum = a1.Text.Length Then
                    CheckedNum = 1
                Else
                    CheckedNum = CheckedNum + 1
                    GoTo ReRead
                End If
            End If
        End If
     End Sub
End Class
```

I Hope The Code was Useful to You